# Back End and Architecture to insert data into Oracle DB using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, architecture

We had an application (Task management) where we create new, update, fetch and delete tasks. 
We made this application using:

1. Front End: HTML, BootStrap, JSPTags
2. Back End: Spring (MVC), and Hibernate (Database interaction)
3. Database: Oracle 11g

*Architecture*: User fills form(task data) in the HTML pages in browser, and on the click of “Submit”, browser will send HTTP POST request to Server where our java code resides. And Spring will give(map) all the data to our JavaObject(Task.java) itself and We pass the task object to our DAO layer where using Hibernate we inserted the data(object) into the database. And on similar basis we performed other operations.

Now we are developing a new application (Script Management) where almost all the basic requirements remains same, as we are going to use Script instead of Task.

**For this new application management told us to use AngularJS instead of JSP/Spring/Hibernate.**

Following technologies we decide to use:

1. Front End: HTML, Bootstrap, AngularJS
2. Database: Oracle 11g
3. Back End: Not confirmed yet (Please guide)
4. Architecture: Not confirmed yet (Please guide)

Please guide me on “Back End” and “Architecture”, how we should achieve the requirements using AngularJS.

Comment: Do you know what REST is?

Answer (score 0):

The Short answer would be:

1) Front End: HTML, Bootstrap, AngularJS

2) Database: Oracle 11g

3) Back End: Restful Services to interact with AngularJS when submitting, and consulting things from a single page (AJAX); this is because AngularJS works under the model of [single-page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application%20single-page-app) app. You will still need Hibernate to persist you data into the DB.

4) Architecture: User fills form(script data) in the HTML pages in browser, and on the click of “Submit”, AngularJS parse this form and sends a JSON object to a restful service (using the HTTP POST method). Then, the restful service translate the JSON object into a Script Object and using the DAO layer (Hiberante) inserts the script into the database.

Comment: thanks a lot.. :) but tell me why anyone, then write front-end code in AngularJS instead of JSP's if he has to write back end java code also.
The development efforts are not much saved by using angularJS.

Comment: @rj86, IMHO, in both approaches, you need to write code at server side: Using AngularJS you will need to write WebServices; using JSP (with MVC or whatever) you will still need to write Servlets, Actions or whatever your framework need ... What you're getting from using AngularJS is two things: One, you server side will be designed thinking in services ... so, your services will not have any GUI logic and can be consumed by any client (JS/html page, android app, iphone app, etc). In other words, decoupling the VIEM from the Business logic.

Comment: Two, your application will be more fluid (as _gmail_ app, for example), where each action does not reloads the entire page (which is what JSP does), only a section of it... Please, If you think that my answer was helpful, vote for it and marked as correct, thanks!